# R calculate the percentage change when the denominator is 0

Tags: r, diff

I am trying to do a simple task in R.
My vector is this:

```
data<-c(0.00,0.04,0.17,0.17,0.17,0.17,0.13,0.00
        0.00,0.00,1.55,1.73,1.73,1.73,1.73,0.19)
```

I am trying to calculate the percentage change from one number to the next. 
The formula is a simple percentage formula:

(next number - previous number)/previous number.

But there is a slight problem in some pairs of number. For example, for calculating the percentage change from the first to second number, the formula would be:

```
(0.04-0.00)/0.00
```

which R will return as Nan even though actually there is a 4% increase. Percentage change between second and third number is easy:

```
(0.17-0.04)/0.04
```

but for pairs where the division takes place by 0.00 is problematic. Is there any way I can tell R that if the equation is divided by zero, than don't divide by zero and express the difference between (next number - previous number) as percentage.

I used the diff function to calculate the difference between each number and previous number.

Comment: *You* have to define the result you want.

Comment: "there is a 4% increase" No, 4 % of zero is zero. If you don't agree with maths you can invent your own maths, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: You **can** program R to give you `(x(t+1)-x(t))/x(t)` when `x(t)` is not zero and `x(t+1)-x(t)` when `x(t)` is zero (you can use the `?ifelse` function), but it's a **really** bad idea to be inconsistent in this way.  You should probably think over your problem more carefully. The simplest thing would be to use the absolute difference `x(t+1)-x(t)` throughout.

Comment: Even ignoring the problem with zero, your results are going to be wildly misleading, since percentages will vary a lot without giving much informatin as to the magnitudes of the data set.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments and sorry for my ignorance of basic maths. I just realized my mistakes and thinking again how to better calculate what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should work probably, although as stated above, your math remains a mystery

```
ifelse(data[-length(data)] != 0, diff(data)/data[-length(data)], diff(data))

## [1]  0.0400000  3.2500000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.2352941 -1.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  1.5500000  0.1161290  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.8901734
```